# how to comfortably concatenate substitutions

Tags: replacement, syntax

Often I have to do perform a succession of substitutions on some expression, and in a notebook the way I know to do that is

```
((((expr /. subst1) /.subst2) /.subst3) ...
```

So everytime I want to add a substitution I have to go back at the beginning of the line and add a `(` and then go at the end of the line and add a `)` and then put the new substitution. 
Is there a more comfortable way to do that? Something like

```
expr // function1 // function2 // function3 ...
```

On the same line, when I have to both apply functions and substitution I have to use again the brackets, because

```
expr // function1 /. subst1 // function2...
```

mess up the order in which things are done: `function2` is applied to `subst1` which is then applied to `function1` which is then applied to `expr`.

Comment: `ReplaceAll` has an operator form. `expr // ReplaceAll[expr -> 1] // ReplaceAll[1 -> 2]`

Comment: You don't need any of those parentheses, since /. is already left associative. Just use `expr /. subst1 /.subst2 /.subst3`.

Comment: you might find `Fold` convenient: e.g., `substitutions = {a -> 1, b -> d, c -> 2, d -> 3}; Fold[ReplaceAll, {a, b, c, d}, substitutions]` .

Comment: Note that replacement can take list arguments, so if the substitutions are independent you could write `expr/.{subst1,subst2,subst3}`.  It they are not independent,  `expr//.{subst1,subst2,subst3}` might give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up, this is perfectly fine:

```
2 /. 2->{2,3} /. 2 -> 4
```

> {4, 3}

And if you need to mix it with functions you can use an operator form of `ReplaceAll`:

```
4 // Sqrt // ReplaceAll[2 -> 5]
```

> 5